# Google Analytics 4: No permissions error in the More Tagging settings

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I created a GA4 property with one Web Data Stream, but when I try to access the "More Tagging Settings" it opens up the section but it shows the message "You do not have permission to access these settings". The user has admin access at all levels (account, property).

I have already researched this online and tried the different solutions offered:

- Making sure I'm not logged into any other Google account
- Use an incognito window
- Try granting a different user full access to the GA4 property and try with that other user.

I continue getting the same message.

Has anyone experienced this and been able to fix it?

[GA4 permissions error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOnuL.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: Happenned to me just now. No solution for me yet.

Comment: Seems like a very fresh bug... hopefully will get resolved fast. They even reference your question on google forum :) https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/166752615/ga4-data-stream-more-tagging-settings-not-working?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The ticket I raised in the Google support community has a workaround that just worked for me. Create a Tag Manager container.

https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/166672964

Comment: Any news on this? Its been a while it was not resolved